# ProgressBar in WPF Slows Down

Tags: c#, wpf

I have read any resource under the sun on how to implement a progress bar in wpf, that will actually reflect the actual progress of a thread. 
Note - ** **I am tied to .NET 4 only**, due to corporate decisions, so any of the newer technics will not be at my disposal unfortunately. 
This is what I have tried so far: 
the method I run is `LoadTable()`. when run directly, it takes about 5 seconds to finish. when it's run in a `BackgroundWorker` it takes about 15 seconds (3 times longer than calling it directly):

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            BackgroundWorker bg = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                // a method that takes time to exceute.
                LoadTable();
                bg.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
```

I also tried to run the method on its own thread and the `BackgroundWorker` that reports to the progress bar on another thread like so:

```
 private void LoadTable_2()
      {
          task = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() => LoadTable()));
      }
```

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadTable_2();
            BackgroundWorker bg = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(i);
                bg.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
```

But in this case, there is no connection between the two threads and there is no way of preventing the progress bar from running to 99, and waiting there until the other thread that executes the `LoadTable` method will finish. **it doesn't report the actual progress of the method's execution**.
My question is how do I use `BackgroundWorker` to actually report the progress without slowing the execution down? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder it's slower when you call `LoadTable()` a hundred times (!) in a loop. You should only call it *once*.

Your `LoadTable()` API apparently doesn't support reporting progress though. There is no way to report progress of a method that doesn't return the current progress.

You should consider showing an intermediate progress bar (set `IsIndeterminate` to `true`). This is the best you can do because you can't know the current progress of `LoadTable()` if it doesn't report it.

Comment: Thanks @mm8. Going for indeterminate progress bar was option I was thinking of as a last resort. My question is if I have any way of reporting progress from a method in .NET 4. Thanks!

Comment: No, not unless the method or API itself actually reports the progress.

Comment: done, thanks! this conversion helped me a lot understand the concept of the `BackgroundWorker` object and how it works.